# String manipulation in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Imagine the context variable {{ url }} outputs `www.example.com/<uuid-string>` where `<uuid-string>` is different every time, whereas the former part of the URL stays the same.

Can one change the output of {{ url }} to instead `www.forexample.com/<uuid-string>`, via *solely manipulating the string in the template* and without involving `views.py` (which I know is the better way to do it, but that's not the question).

An illustrative example would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read about [filters and templatetags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/) - they are a methods that allows you to perform some actions on *variables* in templates.

You can also create your own tags and filters that allow you to perform action non-built into Django template language

Simple example of such filter:

```
    #in templatetags.py
    @register.filter(name='duplicate')
    def duplicate(value):
        return value*2

    #in your template
    <p> {{ url|duplicate }} </p>
```

[You can find more examples here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/). Also there you will find tutorial how to use and create them

Comment: Yep, I've created template tags before. Seems that's the only way.

Comment: If it is not possible to perform edits on *views* level and not possible to manipulate with JavaScript it is only way